# Why do the oil droplets pick up electrons in Milikans Oil Drop experiment?

Tags: electrons, x-rays, ionization-energy

As I currently understand it the x-ray source ionises the air liberating electrons which then stick to the oil drops hence giving them a negative charge which Milikan utilised to acquire a value for e. However I cannot find any explanation/reason for why the electrons would stick to the oil droplets in the first place?

Comment: Why do charges stick to you when you walk across the carpet, leading to a static shock as you touch a door knob? Where do you expect electrons to go?